# CSS - for inline elements it is said that vertical margins(top|bottom) won't apply

Tags: html, css

Since img is an inline element, margin-top and margin-bottom is working.

```
    <img
     src="https://i.imgur.com/ZrTU3VK.jpeg"
     alt="Chuck Taylor All Star Shoe"
     style="margin-top: 10px"
    />
```

*Even if i put display: inline, still vertical margins are working*

Needed explanation, Thanks!

Comment: because image can have margins

Answer (score 3):

Because

> `<img>` is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element); it has a display value of inline by
> default, but its default dimensions are defined by the embedded
> image's intrinsic values, like it were inline-block. You can set
> properties like border/border-radius, padding/margin, width, height,
> etc. on an image.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Very Nice :) resource Mate.